# Can we Obtain Version Number of application from App Store for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, app-store, version, itunes

Instead of using a web-service to get current application version number and comparing it in my code for popping up update alert, **Is there any way to obtain the application version number from App-Store / i-Tunes directly?**

After going through all the comments correct me if i am wrong.

1. **We should not show a Local Notification(as alert) to User regarding availability of new update programatically?**

I went though HIG Guidelines, but could not fing such creteria. So little confused in deciding.

Comment: As web-service is provided by third party, they have lot of creteria to add the tag, so trying to skip that to be frank :)

Comment: So create your own web service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alert updates like this will certainly be against Apple guidelines. For iOS devices, application alerts are displayed by the App store app with a badge displaying the number of updates available. There is nothing a developer needs to do.

If you are worried about the user missing your app update, rest assured that iOS users keep an eye on the app-store app & know that all updates come through it.

However, there are hacky ways by which you can figure out that this is your first run after an update without contacting any web service or iTunes/App store.

One of the hacks known to me:

Fetch the library directory path-

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *libPath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
```

libPath would be something like - /var/mobile/Applications/8CFB747F-9446-44CB-98B9-C6FF1CF7BF93/Library

This random string before /Library changes with every update. You can save this string in NSUserDefaults, and compare the path with the saved string on every launch. If the strings are found to be different, it implies that this is your first run after the update. Display the update alert! Then update the saved string with the new one.

Comment: But Many Applications generally pop up message to the user that "New Update is available" i don't feel this is against apple guide lines,

Comment: If I am Right he wants to get version number from app-store instead of adding a tag in web-service??

Comment: Could you give an example of such an app? Even if it exists, it does not mean it does not violate HIG.

Comment: @akshay: Can you please provide me the ref in HIG, it would be very helpful, as i did not come across such creteria.

Comment: In the hundreds of apps I've used over the 3 years I've owned an iPhone, I've never come across an app that alerts you of updates on its own.

Comment: @SABARISHCHOKKALINGOM: Then ideally you should also provide two buttons, saying 'Update' & 'Ignore', and pressing 'Update' should install your new version. I can bet that's not legally possible on iOS.

Comment: An iOS app will never be able to auto-update itself on a non-jailbroken device. Precisely.

Comment: If you still want to do it, I have added a hack to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You could do an HTTP request to the itunes.apple.com server, while mimicking the User Agent string of iTunes, for your app's URL in the App store, and parse the returned HTML or XML you get back to find the version string, which may or may not be acceptable to Apple's approval team.  But that's unlikely to be worth it, and it also presents an uncommon and unexpected user experience.

Comment: Won't they be having some sort of handshake? I doubt if anyone can pose as the app-store app so easily.

Comment: There are a lot of perl scripts and such around the web that scrape data from itunes using this technique.  Many currently seem to still work.  Of course, Apple could revise iTunes to do something different in the future.  So YMMV.